# Print Arrays and maximum recurring element

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I have 1 string of alphabetical characters. Each character can
occur 1 or more times.I want to put every third character into an array like 3rd,6th,9th,12th
I want to Print the arrays and also the maximum recurring element.

Sample Input 1:

```
S = “abcbjjfgqaazckuccccpcp”
```

Sample Output:

```
[ c, j, g, a, k, c, c]

Maximum recurring character: c
```

Comment: the 3rd, 6th, 9th, 12th, etc... are `[c, j, q, z, u, c, c]` not what you shared `[ c, j, g, a, k, c, c]`.

Comment: To got the 3rd 6th .... you can just give `print (list(s[2::3]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this done using the below code:

```
s = 'abcbjjfgqaazckuccccpcp'

#print ('[ c, j, g, a, k, c, c]') #your reference of 3rd, 6th, 9th is wrong 

print (list(s[2::3]))

#store the char and count as a dictionary
d = {x:s[2::3].count(x) for x in set(s[2::3])}

#get key for max value from dictionary
mkey = max(d, key = d.get)
mval = d[mkey]

#print both key and value
print (mkey,mval)
```

The output will be

```
['c', 'j', 'q', 'z', 'u', 'c', 'c']
c 3
```